# ¿Cómo subir un dibujo o foto canvas a Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, storage, paint

¿alguien sabe si es posible subir una foto a firebase storage que provenga de un dibujo estilo "paint"?
De antemano muchas gracias.

```
            viewCanvas.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            viewCanvas.buildDrawingCache();



            String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    getContentResolver(),viewCanvas.getDrawingCache(),
                    "PruebaFoto01.png", "drawing");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible, pero necesitas hacer algunas conversiones, lo que se manda a Firebase puede ser un array de bytes, eso lo puedes obtener fácilmente de un objeto `Bitmap`. Necesitas obtener el `Bitmap` de tu `viewCanvas`.

```java
Bitmap bitmap = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
// ...
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!